# TransferSqlServerObjectsTask set execution timeout

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I'm developing an SSIS package with a TransferSqlServerObjectsTask in a VB .NET script.
I need to set up an execution timeout on this object in order to stop the task when timeout expires but I've not found this property on the documentation.
Is there a proper way to achieve this functionality?

I'm using the object 
`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferSqlServerObjectsTask.TransferSqlServerObjectsTask` not the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting timeout option for Script Task in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825784/setting-timeout-option-for-script-task-in-ssis)

Comment: That answer is not for my case. I've updated the post to clarify